# Getting error in phase:DOWNLOAD_SOURCE Failed of secret manager cant find keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codebuild

I have this buildspec.yaml for my dotnet project.

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    DOTNET_ROOT: /root/.dotnet
  secrets-manager:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_PARAM: CodeBuild:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_PARAM: CodeBuild:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      dotnet: 3.1
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Command ran in Prebuild
      - echo Restore started on `date`
      - export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
      - pip install --upgrade awscli
      - aws configure set profile $Profile
      - aws configure set region $Region
      - aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_PARAM
      - aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_PARAM
      - cd Dotnetlambda4
      - cd src
      - cd Dotnetlambda4
      - dotnet clean
      - dotnet restore
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - dotnet new -i Amazon.Lambda.Templates::*
      - dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
      - dotnet tool update -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
      - dotnet lambda deploy-function "Dotnetlambda4" --function-role "arn:aws:iam::433377406395:role/LambdaExecutionRole" --region "us-east-1"
      - echo Build finished.
```

These are the logs that buil[Container] 2020/10/05 09:44:36 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2020/10/05 09:44:38 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2020/10/05 09:44:39 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2020/10/05 09:44:39 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src073255159/src
[Container] 2020/10/05 09:44:39 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src073255159/src/buildspec.yaml
[Container] 2020/10/05 09:44:39 No commands found for phase name: install
[Container] 2020/10/05 09:44:39 Processing environment variables

First error I think is
"No commands found for phase name: install". I don't have any idea from where it is coming

Second in the build phase details I am getting error of secret manager cant find the specified secret.

Below is a screenshot

[image: Phase Details]

What should I do?, every time I commit this build is failed with these two errors.

Comment: "No commands found for phase name: install" is not an error. Have you double checked that your secrets are called as you think they are and in the same region as CB?

Comment: Amm How can I check it properly. I can tell that I have created credentials from secret-access-manager and for policies I used resource in policy of codebuild as "*"

Comment: The error msg says that secret called `CodeBuild` with `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` key does not exist. Maybe you've created them in different region, account or misspelled them?

Comment: Region is same and I haven't mispelled it too. Altohugh I have tried key both as key AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and CodeBuild:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, but which one is correct., beacuse in buildpsec.yaml it is CodeBuild:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

Comment: Go to secret manger. Under "secret name" it should write `CodeBuild`. Then if you retrieve the secret value, "secret key" should be `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`. Same for `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

Comment: Guess it worked out? If so I can provide an answer for future reference if you don't mind.

Comment: ya Sure, Definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

"No commands found for phase name: install" is not an error. It is an **information message** that `install` phase has no commands.

The issue was due to **missing/wrong secret manager** `secrets`. To verify the correct settings have to go to Secret Manger console, them  under `Secret Name` it should write `CodeBuild`. Next if you `Retrieve the secret value`, the `Secret Key` should be `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`. Same for `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.